# Yii2-usuario: Debugging on transport layer

Tags: yii2

I cannot send emails out in [Yii2-usuario](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-usuario), e.g. when a password recovery is requested. Email is not working at all.

There is just a flash message saying

```
Unable to send recovery message to the user
```

I think that this is a transport problem. There are tons of things that can go wrong here: firewall issues, tls-/security-settings, self-signed certificates, wrong ports, hostname-typos, ...

How to debug transport layer? How to enable debugging to trace connection to the email service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. In `config/web.php` the mailer was configured as:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
        'htmlLayout' => 'layouts/main-html',
        'textLayout' => 'layouts/main-text',
```

instead of

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'viewPath' => '@app/mail',
        'htmlLayout' => '@app/mail/layouts/main-html',
        'textLayout' => '@app/mail/layouts/main-text',
```

The layout paths were wrong. So the Mailer could not render the messages and failed sending out emails since Yii2-usuario uses formatted emails.

Everything works now.